# Unable to print in Bluej console using PrintWriter

Tags: java, printing, bluej, printwriter

Consider the following code-

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(System.out);
        out.println(1);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I run it on bluej for the first time and get output 1 on console. On running it again i get no output at all and same is the case for any subsequent tries.
Would love to know why this is happening.

Comment: `PrintWriter.close()` will close the underlying output stream, so `System.out` will be closed after this call.

Comment: On removing that statement, i get no output on the console.

Comment: Because the constructor you have [choosen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream)) does no auto-flush. Use either `PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(System.out, true);` or `out.flush()` instead `out.close()`. You want the flush side effect of closing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function stops my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608991/function-stops-my-program)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem why this method only works once is, that the `PrintWriter.close()` method also closes the parent Stream, in this case `System.out`.

So when you call this method the next time, `System.out` will be closed, and nothing will be printed.

So the solution is not to close the `PrintWriter`.
But in this case, nothing is printed, because the output of the `PrintWriter` is not flushed. To do that, you either have to call `out.flush()` yourself or use a constructor which enables auto-flushing on line-endings.

#### tl;dr:

Either use this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(System.out);
        out.println(1);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

or this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        out.println(1);
    }
}
```