# Function stops my program

Tags: java, printing, printwriter

I am trying to use the print function of PrintWriter. When I use this method, my program continues to run but all my other functions doesn't work.

```
    public void printVertices(PrintWriter os) {
        for(int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++) {
            os.print(vert.get(i) + " ");
        }
        os.close();
    }
```

Comment: what is in your vert ?

Comment: @R.Haq its an arraylist of generic objects

Comment: Please post a real [mcve] that reproduces the problem. You don't have "other functions" in the code that you posted, and it's not clear what you mean by "but all my other functions doesn't [sic] work"

Comment: What do you mean by doesn’t work? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: please add more info

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Unable to print in Bluej console using PrintWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471270/unable-to-print-in-bluej-console-using-printwriter/49473364#49473364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, the problem is that you `close` the `PrintWriter`, which also closes the underlying `OutputStream` or `Writer`.

You probably added the `os.close();` statement, because otherwise the `PrintWriter` will buffer the output and you won't see anything printed to the console.

Closing a `PrintWriter` will first `flush()` it, then close it. You probably don't want the second part.

The solution therefore is to simply `flush` the `PrintWriter`:

```
public void printVertices(PrintWriter os) {
    for(int i = 0; i < vert.size(); i++) {
        os.print(vert.get(i) + " ");
    }
    os.flush();
}
```